# Explode com índices de nome (associativo)

Tags: php

Como posso fazer um `explode` numa variável em que depois eu possa acessar ela pelo **índice nominal**, e **não** pelo **índice numérico**?

Segue o exemplo para ficar mais claro:

```
<?php

// Aqui acesso pelo índice
$user = "Diego:25:RJ";
$info = explode(":",$user);
echo "O nome é ".$info[0];

?>
```

Ao invés de usar:

```
echo "O nome é ".$info[0];
```

Gostaria de usar:

```
echo "O nome é ".$info["nome"];
```

No meu exemplo real, resolveria uma certa situação em que a inserção ou remoção de determinada informação poderia ser ruim num uso com o uso de índice numérico.

Comment: é engraçado, eu tento entender por qual motivo a pergunta foi negativada. Acho que foi mais por um critério de gosto do que pela política do site.

Comment: Confesso que também não percebi bem o porquê, parece-me uma pergunta válida, a tentar simplificar um processo, se bem que isso não existe built-in no `explode()`. Já gastei os meus votos hoje, senão até daria +1

Comment: @DiChrist Caso você queira colocar os valores em variáveis, da para fazer assim: http://ideone.com/OV9QMs

Comment: @stderr acho essa solução muito boa também, devia coloca-la como resposta. tendo em conta que é exatamente isso (facilitar o processo)  que o AP parece querer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Além das alternativas com `explode`, você pode usar `preg_match`. Basta informar os índices nominais na própria regra.

```
$string = 'Diego:25:RJ';
preg_match('/(?P<nome>\w+):(?P<idade>\d+):(?P<estado>\w+)/', $string , $matches );


echo $matches['nome'];
echo $matches['idade'];
echo $matches['estado'];
```

[*Exemplo* no ideone](http://ideone.com/6V34gb)

Comment: +1 essa tb é boa.

Comment: essa parece ser muito boa! Vou testar!

Comment: Apesar de eu ter pedido com explode, foi a alternativa que pareceu atender melhor ao que pedi.

Comment: @DiChrist, vi o `explode` como algo genérico, com a intenção de dividir as partes independentemente da forma, por isso trouxe outra alternativa. :)

Answer (score 10):

Pode fazer com [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) para associar cada chave ao valor correspondente:

```
$user = "Diego:25:RJ";
$keys = array('nome', 'idade', 'estado');
$info = array_combine($keys, explode(":",$user));
print_r($info); // Array ( [nome] => Diego [idade] => 25 [estado] => RJ )
```

Desta maneira deve ter a certeza que tem o mesmo numero de chaves (`$keys`) e de valores (`explode(":",$user)`)

Answer (score 7):

É a mesma lógica da do @Miguel, (que já recebeu meu +1), só postei para propor um rearranjo na estrutura, caso vá variar a quantidade de dados dependendo da ocasião:

```
$user = 'Diego:25:RJ';
$keys = 'Nome:Idade:Estado';

$info = array_combine( explode( ':', $keys ), explode( ':', $user ) );
print_r($info);
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/KakbkN)**.

Vale notar que se você reestruturar seus dados como JSON, pode ficar muito mais simples:

```
$json = '{"Nome":"Diego","Idade":25,"Estado":"RJ"}';
print_r( json_decode( $json, true ) );
```

Saída

```
Array
(
    [Nome] => Diego
    [Idade] => 25
    [Estado] => RJ
)
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/tTAI5r)**.

Answer (score 4):

> Essa resposta é baseada no [comentário do @stderr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/149054/explode-com-%C3%ADndices-de-nome-associativo#comment307932_149054)!

Você pode usar o [`list`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.list.php#example-5265) (veja o exemplo "*[Usando list() com índices de array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.list.php#example-5265)*").

```
$user = "Diego:25:RJ";

list($info['nome'], $info['idade'], $info['estado']) = explode(':', $user);

echo $info['nome'].' tem '. $info['idade'] .' anos e mora no estado do '.$info['estado'];
```

Resultado:

```
Diego tem 25 anos e mora no estado do RJ
```

Veja em http://ideone.com/94qRXE

Answer (score 3):

Podes fazer usando um `array()`

```
$user = "Diego:25:RJ";
$info = explode(":",$user);
echo "O nome é ".$info[0];

$infoArr = array('nome'=>$info[0], 'idade'=>$info[1], 'estado'=>$info[2]);

print_r($infoArr); 
echo $infoArr['nome'];
```

Retorno:

```
Array
(
    [nome] => Diego
    [idade] => 25
    [estado] => RJ
)
O nome e Diego
```

Comment: acredito que isso não resolveria meu problema. Imagina se depois vou na variável user e insiro uma informação antes da idade. Iria mudar as informações. A ideia seria não usar os índices numéricos.

Comment: Então tente ser mais específico.

Comment: André, isso já está na pergunta. Eu disse que não queria usar índices númericos.

Comment: Mas se não definires qual seria o indice numerico, creio que não consiga saber em que posição que ele está

Comment: É eu também entendi que é exactamente isto que o @DiChrist não quer.